# Can't log in or disable extension mediawiki

Tags: php, mediawiki

Yesterday I activated the Inputbox extension. Today I can't log in into my account or edit/create pages:

> "There seems to be a problem with your login session; this action has
>   been canceled as a precaution against session hijacking. Go back to
>   the previous page, reload that page and then try again."

I tried deactivating the extension, by deleting `wfLoadExtension( 'InputBox' );` from localsetting.php, but that gave me this error:

```
"[WiL8XrmwKzsAACaYCMUAAABG] 2017-12-02 19:17:51: Fatal exception of type "Wikimedia\Rdbms\DBQueryError""
```

What am I supposed to do?

I'm using:

MediaWiki 1.29.1

PHP 5.6.32

MySQL 5.7

This is my [website](http://sakutest.atwebpages.com/index.php?title=Main_Page). I don't use caching.

I tried:

- Every value for $wgMainCacheType and $wgSessionCacheType.
- Adding $wgCookieSecure = false; to localsetting.php.
- Deleting cookies or using different browsers.